# how do I divide a polynomial by the polynomial that has higher degree?

Tags: polynomials

For example I have $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x^2+2x+1$:

I don't have any problem when I calculate $g(x)/f(x)$, but I tried to calculate $f(x)/g(x)$ and I couldn't find the way to solve it.

1. How should I do the polynomial long division for that situation?
2. If I have an expression $\frac{1}{a+b}$, can I divide it into two different terms?

Comment: **Hint** $g(x) = (x + 1)^2$.

Comment: @Travis I could solve that actual problem by that way, but I mean if it cannot be factored, I was asking for comprehensive ways of division.

Comment: It depends on what you mean. In polynomial long division (for polynomials over, say, $\Bbb Z$ or a field), if divide $f(x)$ by $g(x)$, we effectively find (unique) polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that $f(x) = q(x) g(x) + r(x)$, where the remainder $r$ satisfies $\deg r < \deg g$. If $\deg f < \deg g$, then the only way to write $f$ this way is as $f(x) = 0 \cdot g(x) + f(x)$. Put another way, if $\deg f < \deg g$, in this sense there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x)$ has a lower degree, the quotient will be $0$ and the remainder will be $f(x)$.

$$f(x) = 0g(x) + (x+1)$$

There is no way that the quotient $q(x)$ be something non-zero (constant or higher degree), that would make $q(x)g(x)$ something with degree 1 or less.

Answer (score 1):

When you divid a polynomial $f(x)$ by another polynomial $g(x)$ whose degree is greater, the quotient is $0$ and the remainder is $f(x)$. That is, $f(x)=0\times g(x)+f(x)$.

In your specific situation, you get:$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{x+1}{(x+1)^2}=\frac1{x+1}.$$

Comment: That's incorrect or not complete answer.

Comment: @McCarter What do you think now?

Comment: Still if g(x) is zero then the fraction is not defined/

Comment: In the OP's specific situation, $g(x)=(x+1)^2\ne0$.

Comment: Where does the OP state that?

Comment: The OP mentioned $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$.

Comment: Yes but he doesn't say anything that x cannot be equal to - 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109344/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-mccarter).